# Return a List<> from method

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am wanting to return a `List<string>` from my ASP.NET API Call.  I am getting the compile error below - but am unsure on how to resolve it.

> Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<<anonymous type: string compname, int invoicenum, decimal? invoiceamt, System.DateTime? invoicedate, System.DateTime? invoicepaddate>>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<ITD>`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

And this is my syntax:

```
public IEnumerable<ITD> Get()
{
    List<ITD> result = new List<ITD>();
    XE entities = new XE();
    result = (from a in entities.Companies
              join b in entities.Invoices
              on a.compNumber equals b.compNumber
              select new
              {
                  compname = a.Company1,
                  invoicenum = b.InvoiceNum,
                  invoiceamt = b.InvoiceAmt,
                  invoicedate = b.InvoiceDueDate,
                  invoicepaddate = b.InvoicePaidDate
              });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you need a `ToList()` on your LINQ Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning an `IQueryable` of [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) instead of `IEnumerable<ITD>`. Change your code to this:

```
select new ITD
```

And if you still get error probably it is because you cannot project onto a mapped entity then you need to create a DTO class with needed properties from the `ITD` entity, something like this:

```
public class ITDDTO
{
    public string Company { get; set; }
    //And other properties
}
```

Also don't forget to add `.ToList()` at the end of your query.

Comment: hah - such a quick and simple fix, but one I did not see!  Thank you kindly

Answer (score -2):

Your LINQ query returns a Instance of the interface IQueryable, but your variable `result` is a `List<ITD>`, try doing this instead:

```
List<ITD> result = new List<ITD>(/*Insert LINQ here*/)
```